# Analyzing binary by ZZUF and PEACH fuzzers

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, fuzzing, automated-testing

I have installed two different fuzzer ZZUF and PEACH fuzzers. Unfortunately, my lack of knowledge I could not test C++ binaries by both fuzzers. Testing binaries process is not given PEACH and ZZUF tutorials.

For example abc.c

```
int main(void)
{
    char login[16];
    char password[16];

    printf("Login : ");
    scanf("%s",login);
    printf("Password : ");
    scanf("%s",password);

    if(strcmp(login,"root") == 0){
        if(strcmp(password,"toor") == 0){
            printf("Success.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Fail.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

1. How can I fuzz binary or C code by ZZUF and PEACH fuzzers?
2. Is it possible to test LAVA-M data binaries (base64, uniq, md5sum, who) or OpenSSL 1.1.0f?
   I strongly believe that your help will increase my knowledge.